# Why does the decompiled code for the Int16 class show that MinValue is "--32768" in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, decompiling

Playing with the basic types in C# (.NET Core 2.1), I have just seen that in Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.9.2) the decompiled code for the `Int16` class shows the following:

```
public const Int16 MaxValue = 32767;
public const Int16 MinValue = --32768;
```

Note the two minus signs in the minimum value. Also for `Int32`:

```
public const Int32 MaxValue = 2147483647;
public const Int32 MinValue = --2147483648;
```

And `Int64`:

```
public const Int64 MaxValue = 9223372036854775807;
public const Int64 MinValue = --9223372036854775808;
```

Nonetheless in the decompiled code for the `Double` class the value shows right (with just one minus sign):

```
public const Double MinValue = -1.7976931348623157E+308;
public const Double MaxValue = 1.7976931348623157E+308;
```

Obviously if I try to write `short value = --32768;` the compiler shows an error as I am trying to decrement a constant value.

The [help page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int16.minvalue?view=netcore-2.1) for the `Int16` class shows that the minimum value is:

```
public const short MinValue = -32768;
```

And the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Int16.cs) for .NET Core shows this:

```
public const short MaxValue = (short)0x7FFF;
public const short MinValue = unchecked((short)0x8000);
```

So I am just curious. Why is the decompiler showing that the minimum value for the `Int16` class is `--32768`?

Comment: Asked before, just another bug in VS2017.  They know about it.

Comment: I decompiled it with ReSharper and it looks fine to me, seems like a VS2017 or decompiler "bug"